# How to make my result into list of string?

Tags: python, list

I want to make my result (which consists of top tweeter trends) into a list. Later I will use this list items to use as a query in google news. Can anyone tell me how to make my result as a list and secondly how will I use the list items as separate query in google news (i just need how to do this. I already have a code)

Here is my code:

```
url = "https://trends24.in/pakistan"
req = requests.get(url)
re = req.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(re, "html.parser")
top_trends = soup.findAll("li", class_ = "")
top_trends1 = soup.find("a", {"target" : "tw"})
for result in top_trends[0:10]:
    print(result.text)
```

the output is:

```
#JusticeForUsamaNadeemSatti25K
#IslamabadPolice10K
#promotemedicalstudents51K
#ArrestSheikhRasheed
#MWLHighlights202014K
Sahiwal
Deport Infidel Yasser Al-Habib
BOSS LADY RUBINA929K
Sheikh Nimr
G-10 Srinagar Highway
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a new list, do

```
newlist = []
for result in top_trends[0:10]:
    newlist.append(result.text)
```

or via list comprehension

```
newlist = [result.text for result in top_trends[0:10]]
```

Comment: Great. Thank you Lukas Schmid. Can you tell me how can I use this list as a query for searching in google news.